# IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java, исключения

почему получается исключение?

```
double x49 = 0;
double y49 = 0;
double z49 = 0;
/*
* вычисление. 
*/
String summ = String.valueOf(x49 + y49 + z49);
/*
*  summ  = 50.666 - как вариант
*/
String s = String.format("%.2f", summ);
```

исключение!

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Замени эту строку `String summ = String.valueOf(x49 + y49 + z49);` на `double summ = x49 + y49 + z49;`

Comment: да, спасибо заработало. интересно почему при написании кода eclipse не подчеркнул не правильный вариант.

Comment: де факто он правильный. Но метод `format` не может применить pattern который вы используйте к String объекту